# How to check if a recipient email address domain has TLS implemented?

Tags: c#, email, ssl, smtp

We are trying to check if a recipient email id (domain of a given email id) has TLS implemented or not. If not implemented we cannot send the email. Is there any way in C# to check it? e.g. Following is a service where we can enter any email id and it will tell us if that email domain has TLS implemented or not.   https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver  How to do this in C#?   C# email client comes with the property smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;  question is what will happen if at the recipient side the TLS is not implemented? Will it fail or it will go through? If it fails that's what we want. Our SMTP server has TLS implemented.

I tried STARTTLS command and EHLO from telnet. It gives 250 STARTTLS, which tells me that the destination server has TLS implemented. How to do it programmatically?

smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

Comment: Mail is not delivered end to end from your client to the recipients mail box, but from your client to the mail server of your domain which then sends it maybe over multiple hops to the mail server of the recipients domain. While missing support for TLS in the recipients domain means that there will definitely no TLS used in some part of the delivery it does not mean that support for TLS in the recipients domain guarantees delivery by TLS. And even if all delivery is done with TLS each hop on the way can read the mail since TLS is only used between hops and not end to end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I understood correctly, what you are saying is , when smtpClient.EnableSsl = true; is set, my domain server will check if all the hops till the recipient server has TLS enabled and anyone the hope is unsecured the delivery will fail, correct?  So will my c# code will generate and exception and can I use this exception as a signal to confirm that TLS is somewhere not enabled? I understand TLS is not end to end and its only from my Domain Server to the Recipient Server. we are only looking for Server to Server TLS not end to end, so that is not an issue. Thanks

Comment: No, if you set `smtpClient.EnableSsl = true` it will only make sure that the connection from your client to the first mail hop is secured with TLS. Similar the site your refer to only checks that the recipient domain can accept connections with TLS but it does not say that each connection to it will actually be secured with TLS. None of these methods makes sure that the full path is protected with TLS, not even when you use both together.

Comment: Thank you. We know our SMTP server has TLS implemented. So what we are trying to do is, we want to send emails to ONLY those domains that has TLS implemented. That way we can assure that when we send email from our server to the destination, it will be encrypted all the way from our server till the recipient SMTP server. Correct? For this, we need to check if the recipient's domain server has TLS implemented or not. Thanks again..

Comment: *"That way we can assure that when we send email from our server to the destination, it will be encrypted all the way from our server till the recipient SMTP server. Correct?"* - Wrong.  It is not sufficient to make sure that the delivery from client to first hop will use TLS and that the last hop supports TLS.  First, it does not say anything about all the other hops in between. Also, simply having support for TLS in a hop does not guarantee that TLS will actually be used by the mail server submitting to this hop.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a library like [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit), you can do this:

```
bool supportsStartTls;

using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
    client.Connect ("smtp.host.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.None);
    supportsStartTls = client.Capabilities.HasFlag (SmtpCapabilities.StartTls);
    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

If you want to use MailKit to send mail, you have full control over what happens if STARTTLS is not available.

For example, if you wanted it to fail if STARTTLS is not supported, then use `SecureSocketOptions.StartTls` as the third argument to the `Connect` method.

If you want MailKit to use STARTTLS when it is available but not fail if it isn't, then use `SecureSocketOptions.StartTlsWhenAvailable` instead.

Comment: Thanks. In the following code I think you are referring to my SMTP server correct? client.Connect ("smtp.host.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.None);  We know that our company's SMTP server has TLS implementd. What we want to check is, if recipient's server has TLS capabilities  and make a decision as to email has to be sent or not.

Comment: Do you know what the host address/port is for the recipient's SMTP server? If not, then your only option is to try and use MX DNS records to figure it out and then connect using the MailKit logic in my answer. There's no way to enforce TLS from your SMTP server all the way to the final recipient's SMTP server by just connecting to your own server.

Comment: Yes, I can find out recipient servers host address by using MX DNS records, I may not know the port. But I am assuming I can connect to 25 or 587 and then using MailKit logic on that server to check if TLS is enabled?  My another question is if the destination server has TLS enabled, will the transmission from my sever to that server be encrypted all the way? Thanks

Comment: There’s literally no way to know, all you can really do is assume that it will if it can.